# Google Analytics code snippet incorrect?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the Universal Analytics instead of Classic.

The snippet is

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m
){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'xxxx.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But the help pages I visited all referred to another kind of snippet. For example, this help page:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en&utm_id=ad

As a result, I don't know how to make changes to the above snippet to achieve what I want.

Is the difference in snippet code the result of using Universal vs Classic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enhanced Link attribution is not yet supported in UA (as are GDN integration/Demographics or Remarketings Lists via GA, even though the interface is already there). No clear timeline, but support is to come "soon".

Since Google plans a forced upgrade to UA for all accounts "soon" will hopefully be, ehm, sooner than later.